# How to open upload file dialog automatically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi have a table containing multiple images in a row. If clicked on any image I need to open file upload dialog and get uploaded image into file variable but nor pop and getting uploaded file is working. Can you please help in fixing this jQuery?

My View:

```
{
<table id="listOfProduct">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image1Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image2Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image3Id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image4Id)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductId)

            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Image1Id)
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prodImage"]" class="click"/>

            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Image2Id)
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prodImage"]" class="click"/>

            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Image3Id)
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prodImage"]" class="click"/>

            </td>
            <td>

                @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Image4Id)
                <img src ="@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["prodImage"]" class="click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
<div>
    <input type="file" id="file1" style="display: none" />
</div>
}
```

Script:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.click').on('click', function () {
                $('#file1').on('click').submit(function (e) {
                    debugger;
                    var file1 = $(this).file[0];

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "SellereLogin/uploadProductImage",
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        data: {
                            file: file1,
                            productId: 123,
                            imageId: 12345
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            alert("Data Uploaded: ");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public void uploadProductImage(HttpPostedFileBase file, int productId, int imageId)
{

}
```

Comment: @mason hope so that's tittle looks good now. what you say?;)

Comment: @manson  ha.. ha.. your correct.

Comment: @manson  any help? the ajax call is not hitting to my controller also.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event to the file upload element when you click on the image.

Instead trigger the click event when you click the image.

Attach the change event to the file upload that will make a ajax call.

```
$(function () {
    $('.click').on('click', function () {
        $('#file1').trigger('click');
    });

    $('#file1').on('change', function (e) {
        debugger;
        var file1 = $(this).file[0];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SellereLogin/uploadProductImage",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: {
                file: file1,
                productId: 123,
                imageId: 12345
            },
            success: function () {
                alert("Data Uploaded: ");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am getting error at  `var file1 = $(this).file[0];`

Comment: Put a debug point and use console to check what is going wrong

Comment: i get this error? `Unhandled exception at line 162, column 17 in http://localhost:1064/SellereLogin

0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'file.0' is null or not an object

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`

Comment: I believe `$(this).file[0]` is supposed to be `$(this).files[0];`

Comment: nope not working..  I still get error as cannot read the property 0 : undefined. I am working with var `formData = new FormData($('form')[0])` its not giving any error

Comment: any help? the ajax call is not hitting to my controller also.